# Странное поведение QString (проблема с кодировкой)

Tags: c++, qt, кодировка

Проблема заключается в том, что в разных местах программы функции, работающие со QString, ведут себя по-разному в отношении обработки кириллицы. Это касается и функции `qDebug()` в том числе.

Проиллюстрирую проблему вот таким, утрированным примером. Есть два класса, базовый:

```
ProcessObject(QString name, QObject *owner = Q_NULLPTR, ConfigurationCache* cache = Q_NULLPTR, QString desc = "")
    : DomainModel(name, DomainLevel::Object, owner, cache)      
    , m_description(desc)
    {
        qDebug() << "Это конструктор класса ProcessObject";
    }
```

и наследник

```
#include "ProcessObject.h"

InfoLabel(QString name, QString desc = "", QString vendor = "", QString swrev = "", QString cfgrev = "", QObject *owner = Q_NULLPTR, ConfigurationCache* cache = Q_NULLPTR)
    : ProcessObject(name, owner, cache, desc)
    , m_vendor(vendor)
    , m_softwareRev(swrev)
    , m_configRev(cfgrev)
    {
        qDebug() << "Это конструктор класса InfoLabel";
    }
```

При вызове конструктора класса наследника получаем следующий консольный вывод:

```
Это конструктор класса ProcessObject
��� ����������� ������ InfoLabel
```

Мне непонятна причина, по которой два идентичных вызова функции дают разный результат. Прошу сообщество помочь разобраться с этим вопросом.

Comment: Abyx, отличный совет! Это помогло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подобные проблемы с кодировкой могут быть связаны с тем, что исходники (*.cpp, *.c, .*h) в момент компиляции были в различной кодировке. Всё, что нужно, чтобы устранить данную проблему - единообразно перекодировать все исходники.

В данном случае исходный код класса `ProcessObject` находился в кодировке UTF-8, а `InfoLabel` - в кодировке, отличной от UTF-8. Это и вызвало разницу в интерпретации кириллического строкового литерала.

Вызвать такую неоднородность, могут самые разные факторы: к примеру, код писался несколькими программистами или в разных IDE. Visual Studio по умолчанию сохраняет файлы в кодировке, соответствующей региональным настройкам операционной системы (для России это CP-1251), в то время как Qt Creator позволяет установить кодировку, используемую по умолчанию.